# What's the difference between removing and then installing, and just reinstalling?

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-uninstall

For instance, as `apt-get` relies on some packages in `coreutils`, if you do:

```
sudo apt-get remove coreutils
```

You will not be able to reinstall it by then running:

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

But if I were just to simply try to reinstall `coreutils` with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

It would work. So how come, what's the difference between removing, and then installing, and just using the `--reinstall` option? Don't they do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apt-get remove {package} Remove/Delete an installed package except configuration files.

Remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. If a plus sign (+) is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be installed instead of removed.

--reinstall, Re-Install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.

install.  This option is followed by one or more packages desired for installation. Each package is a package name, not a fully qualified filename.

<sup>Source:[Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)</sup>